# Add AngularJS module in NetBeans

Tags: angularjs, netbeans, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'd like add a ui.boostrap module to my project in Netbeans. I've tried in various ways but to no avail.

This is my app structure:

- WEB-INF

  - views

    - index.html
- resources

  - bootstrap
  - js

    - controllers

      - AppController.js
    - lib

      - angular

        - angular.js
        - ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.min.js <- ui.boostrap
        - etc...
    - app.js
    - directives.js
    - filter.js
    - services.js

I copied file ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.min.js to folder js/lib

Head of file app.js

```
var App = angular.module('MyApp', ['MyApp.filters', 'MyApp.services', 'MyApp.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

In index.html I added:

```
<script src="resources/js/lib/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: So what isn't working? Any errors thrown?

Comment: When I adding this just angular not working. Example - Controllers js but any errors thrown

Comment: Check Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools (or similar tool) to make sure the request to load the JS file is OK. Also I don't see the angular directory in lib directory. Is it there?

Comment: @ladar yes it's there. I've corrected my post. Errors In chrome JS Console: Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).controller(...).directive(...).directive(...).animation is not a function(anonymous function) @ ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.min.js:8.    --------------                  AND        --------   Uncaught Error: No module: template/accordion/accordion-group.html

Comment: Then you are missing some JS sources, where the animation (or whatever) is defined. I'd suggest to check documentation of ui-bootstrap-tpls and other used JS libraries